# Bootstrap JS not working with BrowserSync

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to create Bootstrap project with BrowserSync, however it seems the JS isn't working. The project files can be found here: https://arkroy@bitbucket.org/arkroy/fti_corp.git

I've tried pulling from bower_components directly, CDN and by just copying the individual files into the dist/js folder.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was uncss removing styles classes used by javaScript